# 'high' .5V 'low' .05V instructions sent into ALU determine how hot the circuit gets or similar?

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, circuit-design, heat

If you were to send instruction sets of all 1's which sink voltage into a circuit. Would that cause the circuit to heat up in oppose to sending 0's? My logic behind this is the sink it requires more voltage and since transistors are near perfect the more heat is generated the more voltage is passed through. So running instruction in which more 1's come in would heat up more then more 0's. Or am I thinking of this wrong?

Comment: circuits do not `sink voltage` ... circuits `sink current`

Comment: Aside from the details of different logic families, also consider as a thought experiment that you assign ground to the more positive rail and -3.3 (or whatever) to the more negative rail.  All that has changed is the naming of the power connections.  Now does it make sense that all logic 1 would use less power?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are thinking it wrong.

Most modern circuits are built with CMOS technology, where static logic 0 and static logic 1 itself does not consume current nearly at all, but transitioning between the logic states do consume energy.

So basically, if you have a system with a clock signal, the higher the clock frequency is, the more current the system consumes.

Answer (score 2):

tl; dr: there is a pattern-vs.-power relationship, but not in the way you think.

Some logic families do draw more power in one state vs. another:

- TTL: input current for '0' is about 10x more than '1'
- NMOS: uses a depletion-mode FET pull-up to make a logic '1', so
  draws current only when driving 0

CMOS on the other hand does not have a static current draw from driving 1 or 0. It only dissipates power while it is changing state as it charges / discharges its load capacitance. CMOS also loses some power to leakage current, that is, the FETs don't turn off completely; this the same regardless of what state its in.

These two CMOS power dissipations are referred to as *dynamic power* and *static power*, respectively.

Let's set aside leakage for now. In a modern CMOS device, it's not whether the logic inputs are '1' or '0', but if they are *changing state*. That's because each state change uses a little packet of energy to charge or discharge the load capacitance downstream. The more state changes there are in a given time, the more power gets used. This is expressed as an equation: $$ P_{dyn} = C V^2f $$

Where *C* is the total capacitance being switched and *f* is the toggling rate.

More about all that here: https://semiengineering.com/knowledge_centers/low-power/low-power-design/power-consumption/

And here: [https://course.ece.cmu.edu/~ece322/LECTURES/Lecture13/Lecture13.03.pdf](https://course.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eece322/LECTURES/Lecture13/Lecture13.03.pdf)

So back to the beginning. Is there a power vs. pattern relationship? Of course. An input state change can be magnified quite a bit by the logic. An example:

- ALU processing the operation (0 - 1): all of its outputs change state, as well as the adders and carry chain. Lots of dynamic draw.
- ALU processing (0 + 1) only changes the LSB and first adder. Not so much dynamic draw.

In my own work experience (AI ASICs), the number of neural activations varies depending on the input data, and thus the power: 'brighter', more complex input data consume more power per inference than simpler or darker data. More stuff is toggling as the network layers are processed.

The takeaway: **when considering power dissipation, the data pattern used in making that estimate or benchmark matters**, which is kind of what you were getting at.